# Is there a stored procedure to update a boolean value in one table when an insert occurs on another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-trigger

I have two tables, PatientMedicalHistory and PatientMedicineTable. 
The Patient medical history has the following fields -

```
PatientMedicalHistoryID Primary Key for PatientMedical History Table
Medications Boolean for existence of prior medications
Allergies   Boolean for existence of allergies
Diseases    Boolean for existence of prior diseases
FamilyHistory   Boolean for existence of hereditary conditions
```

The Patient Medicine Table history contains the following fields -

```
PatientMedicalHistoryID Primary, Foreign Key for Patient Table
MedicineID  Primary, Foreign Key for Medicine Table
```

Is there a way to create a trigger to update the Medications boolean value when an entry is inserted into the Patient Medicine table?

Comment: You should always carefully consider whether you *should* store data that you can derive. By storing it, you introduce the possibility that it's *inconsistent* with the data it's derived from. Is there a reason you shouldn't just query the medicine table for the Patient when you need to know if they've had meditcations?

Answer (score 0):

An AFTER INSERT trigger should be what you're looking for. The link below is a tutorial on creating it.
http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-create-trigger/

Answer (score 0):

As you already stated in your question this can be done via [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Specifically, you're interested in `AFTER INSERT` triggers.
Your code would look roughly as follows

```
-- recreating the trigger to be sure
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[YourTrigger] 
GO


CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[YourTrigger]
ON [dbo].[PatientMedicineTable]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE h
    SET  h.[Medications] = 1
    FROM Inserted i, [dbo].[PatientMedicalHistory] h
    WHERE h.PatientMedicalHistoryID = i.PatientMedicalHistoryID
END
GO
```

Please do note that AFAIK you handle boolean values in SQL Server via setting bit field via 1 or 0 but you may need another option.

Comment: Hi Bohdan, Thank you for your help. I tried creating the trigger, but I encountered an ambiguous column name error on the PatientMedicalHistoryID.

Comment: Is it possible that the error is occurring because the referential integrity may be a problem? Or could it be because an alias needs to be used for the PatientMedicalHistory table?

Comment: Hu Shashank, thanks for writing up. No, the problem is that both tables have a column with the same name and since there was no alias in WHERE clause SQL struggled to resolve which exactly column was needed. So I've updated the original answer to provide alias for a table the same way as here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0cfe2fb4-ccd8-435a-bc67-48e95f51e484/using-alias-in-update-sql-statement?forum=transactsql